# Gradle build failed: Failed to create MD5 hash for file, Windows defender finds A threat

Tags: java, android, android-studio, windows-defender

I'm trying to build my android app. It was working fine when suddenly windows defender gave me a message that it had found a threat, and directly after I get an error message:

```
Error:Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'destinationDir' during up-to-date check.
```

> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'C:\Users\userx\folderx\folderx\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug\com\apps\sdc\app\global\randomclass.class'.

This happens every time I try to build my project.

Thanks in advance.

**Solution:**

Disable Windows defender and it should work.

Comment: Have you enabled instant run?

Comment: Even if I disabled it, it gives the exact same error

Comment: Then this might be due to antivirus, windows defender, here.Try disabling your antivirus and do it again.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the issue, but isn't there any other way than disabling my antivirus?